# SupportMapFragment not working properly in Activitygroup in two different tab

Tags: android, google-maps, activitygroup

I am using below code for showing map in two different tab with different id. It works perfectly if I use it for single activity but when I use it for two different activities from the different tab.

Case 1

- click on first tab the it showing map properly
- click on second tab it showing map of first tab

Case 2

- click on second tab it showing map properly
- click on first tab it showing map as it was in second tab
  I observed previous map is overleap  with current map so not able to see my current tab map

  ```
  <fragment
  android:id="@+id/map1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" >
  </fragment>
  ```

Comment: `ActivityGroup` has been deprecated for nearly two years. You can use action bar tabs, or `ViewPager` and `PagerTabStrip`, for displaying Maps V2 maps in tabs. Or, try the new `FragmentTabHost` (though I haven't gotten that working just yet).

Comment: @CommonsWare but i want to show custom tabview like iphone

Comment: Then use `TabHost` with views, like `MapView`, as the tab children. Or, try the new `FragmentTabHost`.

Comment: @CommonsWare can we customize FragmentTabHost like iphone tab?